# Looking for a spreadsheet-like control for Cocoa

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstableview

I'm looking for a grid view / table view / spreadsheet-type control for Cocoa and can't seem to find anything that's in any reasonable state.

I've tried using NSTableView but it's not really meant to be a single cell control.

NSCollectionView doesn't seem to be right either.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why don't you use cell-based NSTableView (or even some simple kind of view-based one, since the Apple's NSCell-deprecation)?

Comment: "a single cell control."? Not sure what this means. Set number of row & columns to 1 and you'd have a single cell NSTableView… Cell based NSTableView's have one cell per… cell. View based NSTableView's can have multiple (nested) views per cell. Not sure what you're looking for here.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear. I would use NSTableView, but it seems that it's designed to allow you to select individual rows, but not cells. At least not without a lot of overriding or subclassing. I'm looking for a way to have a very Excel looking/acting spreadsheet control (obviously without the underlying math). Something that I can select/copy/paste/edit text inside cells. MBTableGrid is pretty close, but it's missing a lot of things and looks like it's not maintained any more. Thanks.

Comment: Hello from 2016! :-) Any luck in you search?

Answer (score 1):

While Matt Ball's spreadsheet view (https://github.com/mattball/mbtablegrid/, mentioned above) is several years old, it does still compile on El Capitan. It must be easier as a starting point than working from scratch. There are several forks of the repository, most notable this one that does seem to be actively developed:

https://github.com/pixelspark/mbtablegrid

It seems like it would be better for those interested to pool contributions than create something new!

Answer (score 1):

We now have [NSGridView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsgridview), which is most likely what any future person reading this will want to use.

Comment: Can you elaborate? All examples for NSGridView I have seen are about preference panes.