# How can I select multiple fields in the results grid in Mysql Workbench on MacOS X?

Tags: mysql-workbench, macos-sierra

When selecting multiple fields using Command click, the whole rows are selected.

Tried lot of possible combinations of keys - didn't find how to select just some fields. This is possible on windows using Ctrl click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the way the native control works on macOS it's not possible to select multiple individual cells there. On Windows we use a custom control which supports that feature.

Comment: Thank you for answering. 
It seems that this is very connected to this one: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29331806/looking-for-a-spreadsheet-like-control-for-cocoa

am I right? 

Hope this gets resolved soon, it is very useful feature for me. Workaround of course is editing the select several times to get what you need, but that is ... workaround :)

Comment: Is there any workaround for MacOS to select multiple cells?

Answer (score 0):

I just tested now: sep 2023

- With click + shift = select all rows between rows you clicked
- With click + command = select rows you clicked